# Prevent Magento changing product stock status when the quantity drops below zero

Tags: php, magento

I need to find a way to over-ride the "Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock" value in Magento 1.7. I want the stock status of the product to always be In Stock regardless of the current stock value. Magento's admin doesn't allow you to set a negative number in this field (I had thought I could just set this field to -9999 and not have to worry about it). However a negative value is always saved as 0. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

no there is no way around to save a negative value.

If you need that you product is salable even if you have a negative quantity you
can set in the System->configuration->Inventory->Product Stock option
the backorders option to "Backorders".

Bye
Giuseppe

Answer (score 0):

I have had limited success by putting the out of stock trigger number to a very high number that the stock quantity will never reach. It seems to be working by keeping the items status as in stock even if the quantity is zero.